# Ignore folders beginning with dot in IntelliJ

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

In project I work on there are folders with name started with dot sign. They are used by external tool to generate actual code/properties variation based on some properties. IntelliJ complains about java classes in these folders (path doesn't correspond to package name). What I'd like to do is to force the compiler to ignore specific folders (they shouldn't be used in build anyway). I found Settings->Compiler->Excludes option but I can't see the dot started folders when I try to specify exclusions. Pasting folder path doesn't work either. Not sure if it is like that because of Intellij or mac hidden folder issue. Any hints?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the module editor, set the folder to be excluded from the project, i.e totally ignored. Select the folder and then click on the "Excluded" button. Then the folder will be shown in red and will not even show up in IDEA project view, and no indexing or compiling will take place on this folder.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can "Show Hidden Files and Directories" which should be the last icon in the Select Path window.

[image]

Comment: where is this "show hidden files and directories"? i cant find it

Comment: @slier I have added a screen shot.